# What is the difference between a Pod and a Job resources in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

Is Pod and Job resource the same ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ""
  labels:
```

or

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ""
  labels:
```

The `Job` will still create a pod I think. Just wondering when do I use one instead of the other.

Answer (score 28):

Pod is basic unit to express a runnable process on Kubernetes.

Job is a higher level abstraction that uses pods to run a **completable task**.

You might be thinking of using a pod with `restartPolicy: Never` to run a **completable task**. But in the event of node failure, pod on that node managed by Job are rescheduled to other node but an unmanaged pod is not.

Job also has extra features like `completions` and `parallelism` using which you can run multiple instances.

Comment: I think that a Job with `restartPolicy: Never` and `backoffLimit: 0` is equivalent to a bare pod... am I right?

Answer (score 17):

#### Pods

As a container orchestrator, K8S wraps containers with a unit of work called a Pod.

All the other resources and components (I'll exclude Kubelet) are part of K8S modular architecture and designed to provide the pods different capabilities like: scheduling, scaling, internal and external networking, handling failures, managing cpu and memory and more.

(*)  Kubelet is the only component which interacts with the Container Runtime.

You can say that a Pod wraps one or more containers under it just like multiple processes are running inside a VM. If you want to reach to one of them from outside, you will have to refer to the IP of the host and the port of the process (container).

#### Jobs - From the controller side

(*) If this a bit advanced - just view the yaml example below and skip to the next section.

The Job resource is part of a group of resources that is responsible for referring to a state of pods directly (see comment on *directly* at the end).

So together with other resources like ReplicaSet / Deployments, StatefulSet and CronJob they have a dedicated Controllers that runs on the control plane in a infinite loop and watches for **changes to pods which were created by the corresponding resource type**. 
So if a pod was created by a Job resource:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-computational-job
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
         name: my-computational-job
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-image
        image: some-image
      restartPolicy: Never #<---- We will discuss this below
```

Every change that will apply to this type of resource will be inspected by the Job controller that looks at the new desired state of the resource (or in other words, what should be the pods new state) and decide what is the current action that need to take place - tell K8S to delete the previous pods and create new ones (like in the case where an image or the label selector was changed) or keep the current state of the pods and just change other configuration which are related to the them.

#### Jobs - From the resource side

So what is so special in this type of resource? 
We saw that like other resources it manages Pods state (with the corresponding Controller).

The main point here is *how those pods are being configured?* 
 Which can also be referred to as: 
***What type of applications should I run with this resource?***

**The answer is: Applications that needs to perform a dedicated task and terminate afterwards**.

For that, the Job resource should support configuration which relevant to this types of tasks:

1 ) Restart Policy - If we look at the `restartPolicy` field in the yaml above - we can specify values like `onFailure` and `Never` but we can't specify `Always` because it will be opposed to the type of tasks that should run with this resource.
Read more in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#handling-pod-and-container-failures).

2 ) Running multiple Pods sequentially or in parallel - Just like we have the `replicas` field in the Replica Set / Deployment spec which will specify how many pods should K8S scale, the Job resource has a different syntax that will also tell K8S how to run those pods.

To run multiple Jobs you need to specify the number of pods in the `.spec.completions` field. Those jobs will run one by one by default.
In order to run them in parallel you need to specify how many pods should run in parallel in the `.spec.parallelism` field.

The Job resource support more advanced configuration options - read more in [Parallel execution for Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs).

3 ) Failure policy -  In cases we'll need to fail a Job after number of retries we can setup the `.spec.backoffLimit` field. 
 Read more in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-backoff-failure-policy).

---

**More references:**
Patterns for parallel computation - see [Job Patterns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-patterns).

Running multiple Jobs based on a common template - see [Parallel Processing using Expansions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/#using-jobs-in-real-workloads).

---

**Comment from the 'Jobs - From the controller side' section:**
It is hard to say that a resource is responsible for referring to a state of pods *directly* because in K8S every part of the architecture has a specific modular role -  but in case of controllers it is not far from that because they do quiet a lot.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! It helped not only to understand the difference between those two but also to understand when to use which resource.

Answer (score 4):

Use Jobs if your tasks will complete (e.g. computes π to 2000 places and prints it out).

Under the hood, Job uses Pods for the computation. Imagine Job is a higher level of abstraction than Pods.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/